# Font Size Fluctuation and Inconsistency

Tags: fonts, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, font-size

I am currently working on a ST2 powered web-app and experiencing something odd with the consistency of font-size across the entire app. Initially I thought it might be due to a font-size attribute I was setting in the custom SASS file, but when I strip all "font-size" properties from my SASS file I still see fonts rendering inconsistently.

We are pushing views from multiple "root" views, but with no font-size property set I would expect all fonts to render the same size. Am I missing something? Please note I am not talking about font-size across multiple devices...this is font-size in general for the app itself.

Check out the attached images and the path taken to arrive each view. They are the exact same view with same components - the only difference is the path in which the user has taken to arrive there. Keep in mind I have removed ALL custom font attributes, so it is purely referencing Sencha's styles at this point (have tested on Chrome, iOS emulator, and iPhone running app locally).

**User Path:** Dashboard View (Root View) > Team Profile

[image]

**User Path:** Dashboard View (Root View) > Programs View (Root View) > Team Profile

[image]

Notice how the second "Team Profile" view has a larger font size? With no font's set for the entire app I would expect it to be the same regardless of how you arrive at the view. Can someone please explain to me what might be going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running it in a browser like chrome and using dev tools to inspect the element? You should be able to track down the rogue CSS property and whether it was created by your application or not

Comment: Yeah, I have scoured the DOM trying to figure out what might be causing the issue. There are zero font attribute values set by myself and only a few in the core Sencha files. I am almost certain at this point, it has something to do with the way views are being pushed in the Sencha architecture itself.

Comment: I have the same issue. Only mine is larger on the first view, and smaller on the second view, and subsequent views.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue for me was not including `styleHtmlContent: true` in the config of the view with the larger font. If you don't have that option set in the view, add it and see if it makes a difference.